# Pandas groupby create a list of values from several columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe

```
df = ID  C1  C2  C3  C4
     1   a   b   r    q
     1   b   e   g    h
     2   p   a   z    p
     1   r   a   n    m
```

I want to get list of values in C1, C2 per ID.
So I will have:

```
out = ID  l 
      1  [a,b,r,e]
      2  [p,a]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Why 'e' is missing from ID==1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) - output is sorted:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ID')[['C1','C2']].apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist())
        .reset_index(name='l'))
print (df1)
   ID             l
0   1  [a, b, e, r]
1   2        [a, p]
```

Or with [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) - output is with original order:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ID')[['C1','C2']].apply(lambda x: pd.unique(np.ravel(x)).tolist())
        .reset_index(name='l'))
print (df1)
   ID             l
0   1  [a, b, e, r]
1   2        [p, a]
```

Another idea with remove missing values and duplicates:

```
df1 = (df.melt(id_vars='ID', value_vars=['C1','C2'], value_name='l')
         .drop_duplicates(['ID','l'])
         .dropna(subset=['l'])
         .groupby('ID')['l']
         .agg(list)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   ID             l
0   1  [a, b, r, e]
1   2        [p, a]
```

EDIT: For separate columns use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby('ID')[['C1','C2']].agg(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist()).reset_index()
print (df2)
   ID         C1         C2
0   1  [a, b, r]  [a, b, e]
1   2        [p]        [a]
```

Comment: I get the error 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'' although columns are from the type 'Object', any idea?

Comment: @Cranjis - there are missing values I guess

Comment: And if I want a seperate column for C1 and C2?

Comment: @Cranjis then use `df1 = (df.groupby('ID')[['C1','C2']].agg(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist()).reset_index())` changed `apply` to `agg`

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your dataframe then group by ID and finally get unique values:

```
>>> df.melt('ID', value_name='l').groupby('ID', as_index=False)['l'].unique()

   ID             l
0   1  [a, b, r, e]
1   2        [p, a]
```

**Update**

> And if I want a seperate column for C1 and C2

```
>>> (df.melt('ID', var_name='col', value_name='l')
       .groupby(['ID', 'col'], as_index=False)['l']
       .apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist())
       .pivot(index='ID', columns='col', values='l')
       .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())

   ID         C1         C2
0   1  [a, b, r]  [b, e, a]
1   2        [p]        [a]
```

Comment: I get the error AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: Do you use `['l']` before using `unique`?